# null Pointer Exception when parsing date with Simple Date format

Tags: android, date, firebase, nullpointerexception, datetime-parsing

I have a problem with converting my String into date and it gives me a null pointer exception and I've tried everything.

This is how I enter my String into my database from calendarView

```
mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            string = (i1 + 1) + "/" +i2 + "/" + i;
}
        });

String key = mDatabase.push().getKey();

                HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                dataMap.put("Date", date);
                dataMap.put("Key", key);
 mDatabase.child(key).setValue(dataMap);
```

Then when I retrieve it from my database I format it like this

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").child("JMHyOvgCDvdKEZuReJvdGcExEnX2").child("HomeFragment").child("FreezerItems");
        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String,String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (value != null){
                    String name = value.get("Name");
                    String date = value.get("Date");

                    try {
                        dateFormat = new Date();
                        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy", Locale.US).parse(date);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        Log.wtf("FailedtoChangeDate", "Fail");
                    }
```

My problem is when I try to convert the string to M/dd/yyyy format even though the date's format in string is like this "5/30/2018"

A screen shot when I debug it [image]

Comment: also post the value of this variable here String date = value.get("Date");

Comment: updated my answer check , it will work :)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please post your stacktrace (get hold of it somehow, it’s vital).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer :-

Your date input **05/20/2018**

```
String input_date = "05/20/2018";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(input_date );  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: updated this answer for 05/20/2018 date , Try it and it will work :)

Comment: check this value again String date = value.get("Date"); and debug your code

Comment: I even tried to copy how the data is entered and pasted where the data is being retrieved so no errors but still won;t work

Comment: is it still crashing ?

Comment: yea, also I'm not sure how to debug my code, Ill update my question

Comment: yes please do it and just how to use debugger and set check points , it will help dear :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171428/discussion-between-kristofer-and-quick-learner).

Comment: While your code works, (1) it’s still using the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` also used in the question, (2) it doesn’t seem to give any guidance on how to solve the `NullPointerException` that the question is about.

Comment: FYI i have explained the reason for null pointer exception which is due to wrong format :) , correct me if i have posted wrong code or post your answer explaining everything

Comment: A wrong format would give a `ParseException`, not a `NullPointerException`. So no, you have not explained,

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is very useful. It shows that `value` returns `null` for both name and date. So the values you try to take out from this map are not in there. This is why `date` is `null` and you get your `NullPointerException`.

Why there is no date (and no name) in the map lies outside the code that we can see in the question, so I cannot tell.